# combobox search

Tags: c#, search, combobox

Интересует вопрос как в combobox реализовать поиск не по первой букве/цифре/символу, а по вхождению в строку?

[image: поиск в combobox]

Ибо страндартными AutoCompleteMod и AutoCompleteSource выводит только по первой. И много данных не отображается.
Хранятся данные в БД. Связаны через bindingsource.
Пробовал в событиях

```
private void cb_Projects_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)

private void cb_Projects_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

и в загрузке главной формы

```
 this.cb_Projects.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                var st = from p in db.Projects select p.ProjectName.ToString();
                string[] ar = st.ToArray();
                this.cb_Projects.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(ar);
                this.cb_Projects.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                this.cb_Projects.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Но, как выходит, это не эффективно

Нужен какой-то алгоритм подсчёта символов в строке или ещё что-либо.
Заранее спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Если пользуйтесь BindingSource, то нужно использовать его в полной мере, у него есть метод Find и свойство [Filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) которое вам должно помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> func(List<string> весь_массив,string искомая_подстрока)
{
    return весь_массив.Where(x=>x.Contains(искомая_подстрока)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Есть ли ещё какие-либо пути для решения данного вопроса?

Comment: @MarkKovak напишите чем именно не подходит данный метод, и тогда будет ответ. Способы есть, но смысл тот же

Comment: @MarkKovak если я правильно понял, данные в combobox вы с БД тяните...а с помощью чего?? EF используете или что -то другое?